# How to get the Entity POCO type from the Entity Proxy type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm migrating a project from EF6 to EF-Core.  The Metadata API has changed significantly and I am unable to find a solution to this:

Under EF6 I could find the POCO Type from the Proxy Type using:

```
ObjectContext.GetObjectType(theEntity.GetType)
```

This, however, does not work under EF-Core (no `ObjectContext` class).  I've searched and searched to no avail.  Does anyone know how to get the POCO type from either the `entity` or the `entity proxy type`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF Core supports proxies via [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies/) nuget package. So, to unwrap the proxy class you can use this approach:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

....

public static Type GetEntityType(DbContext context, object entity)
{
    if(entity == null || context == null){
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }

    return context.Model.FindRuntimeEntityType(entity.GetType()).ClrType;
}
```

Comment: This appears to be correct based on MS Learn web site documentation:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelextensions.findruntimeentitytype?view=efcore-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=efcore-7.0

Answer (score 9):

There is no perfect way. You could for example check the namespace. If it's a proxy it'll

```
private Type Unproxy(Type type)
{
    if(type.Namespace == "Castle.Proxies")
    {
        return type.BaseType;
    }
    return type;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

EF Core does not support the `ObjectContext` API. Further more, EF Core doesn't have proxy types.

You can get metadata about entity types from `IModel`.

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    // gets the metadata about all entity types
    IEnumerable<IEntityType> entityTypes = db.Model.GetEntityTypes();

    foreach (var entityType in entityTypes)
    {
        Type pocoType = entityType.ClrType;
    }
}
```

Comment: In EF Core 2.1 lazy loading was added and it works as in EF6 - it creates proxies - so `entity.GetType()` won't return the type of entity, but the proxy instead. This answer is no longer true.

Answer (score 0):

With Entity Framework Core `ObjectContext` is not available. Similar to @Mariusz Jamro answer but without the string you can test if the object implements the `IProxyTargetAccessor` interface.

Although the interface exposes the method `DynProxyGetTarget` it cannot be used in this instance because you get back the proxy again . Instead you have to look at the base type as demonstrated in the Mariusz's answer.

```
private Type UnProxy<T>(T entity) => entity switch
{
  null => typeof(T),
  IProxyTargetAccessor proxy => proxy.GetType().BaseType,
  var e => e.GetType()
};
```